# How do iterate through all errors for a WP_Error object?

Tags: errors, wp-error

I have a block of code that I know contains multiple errors which come from the [wpmu_validate_blog_signup](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpmu_validate_blog_signup/) function. The error object is part of the $result array.

```
$result = wpmu_validate_blog_signup($domain_name, $domain_title);

    if (is_wp_error($result['errors'])) {
        $all_errors = $result['errors']->get_error_messages();
        foreach ($all_errors as $key => $value) {
            wc_add_notice($value, 'error');
        }
    }
```

Is get_error_messages not supposed to return an array of all messages? Shouldn't `$value` be the error string? Calling `$result['errors']->get_error_message()` correctly gets the first error string, but I can't seem to figure out how to get them all. Calling `$result['errors']->get_all_messages()` returns `(Array)`

Update:

Discovering that this was a multidimensional array, I came up with this code which works:

```
if (is_wp_error($result['errors'])) {
        $all_errors = $result['errors']->errors;
        //var_dump($all_errors);
        foreach ($all_errors as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == 'blogname'){
                foreach($all_errors[$key] as $key2 => $value){
                    wc_add_notice($value, 'error');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But this feels clunky. What if I don't know the array keys? Feels like there should be a better way to handle this, so please advise if you can see how to make it better.

Comment: if that code correctly returns 1 error, `$all_errors` probably only has 1 error. Enable debug_log in wp and debug `$all_errors`, like this: `error_log(' all errors array: '.print_r($all_errors,true).'</pre>');`.